# How to access a parent value inside an array in yup validation

Tags: validation, yup

I have defined a yup schema

```
export const ValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    dateTo: yup
        .date()
        .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)

   uebernachtungen: yup.array().of(
     yup.object().shape({
     ort: yup
            .string()
            .trim()
            .max(100, Maximum100CharactersMessage)
            .required(MandatoryFieldMessage),

    bis: yup
            .date()
            .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)
            .max(yup.ref("dateTo"), "display message") }))
})
```

I just want to use the value of `dateTo` inside the array, so that all the `bis` in the `uebernachtungen` will not be allow do have a value greater than `dateTo`.

The problem is that I can access items inside the array like `ort` but I cannot access items out of it like `dateTo`.

So in this case yup.ref("dateTo") will return undefined but `yup.ref("ort")` will be correct. It seems that array has its own context and I cannot access to the parent context.

How would be this possible?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example or at least post the whole schema.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I updated it.

Comment: can you tell me what do you want to achieve with dateTo value?

Comment: I want that all the `bis` inside `uebernachtungen` not to be allowed to have a value greater than `dateTo`

Comment: Have you tried anything with "test"? https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

Comment: Yes ```function isGreaterThanDateTo(this: yup.TestContext, value: Date) {
 

  var dateTo = this.resolve(yup.ref("dateTo"));

  return dateTo && value && dateTo.getDate() === value.getDate();
}```

Comment: In the above function the `resolve` method is able to retrieve `ort` but not `dateTo`. It is not available in the `TestContext`.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I came through similar issue. I used this workthrough with success.

**Idea**: Pass whole form-data as a context to the schema and access any form value using

**`this.options.context`**

```
 const ValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
     dateTo: yup
         .date()
         .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)

     uebernachtungen: yup.array().of(
         yup.object().shape({
             ort: yup
                 .string()
                 .trim()
                 .max(100, Maximum100CharactersMessage)
                 .required(MandatoryFieldMessage),

             bis: yup
                 .date()
                 .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)
                 .test('dateToCheck', 'display message', function (value) {
                    // access dateTo from passed context
                   if(value>this.options.context.dateTo) return false
                   return true }),

         })) })
```

> Passing Context

**Without Formik**

Send your **Form data** as a context while validating

```
 ValidationSchema.validateSync(data, {context: form_data})
```

**With Formik**

Use **validate** instead of **validationSchema**

Pass your **Form data** as 4th argument in **validateYupSchema** which represents context and can be accessed later in schema.

Pass your **schema** as 2nd argument in **validateYupSchema**.

```
    <Formik
      validate={(value) => {
        try {
          validateYupSchema(value, ValidationSchema, true, value);
        } catch (err) {
          return yupToFormErrors(err); //for rendering validation errors
        }

        return {};
      }}

       onSubmit={} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work, if i understood correctly ur question...

[Example of using test to get value from yup scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3QCT.png)

Comment: This is something I tried already. This will not wok since `dateTo`  is not part of the array context.

Comment: Well, u can get it using .test('test', 'test', function(item) { console.log(this.parent) }) where this.parent is ur entire yup scheme, so u could get something like const {dateTo} = this.parent

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It worked fine for me.

```
import { array, date, object, string } from 'yup';

export const ValidationSchema = object().shape({
  dateTo: date().required('MandatoryFieldMessage'),
  uebernachtungen: array().when('dateTo', (dateTo, schema) =>
    schema.of(
      object().shape({
        ort: string().trim().max(100, 'Maximum100CharactersMessage').required('MandatoryFieldMessage'),
        bis: date().required('MandatoryFieldMessage').max(dateTo, 'display message')
      })
    )
  )
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a global variable `dateToTmp` and assign value by test method:
check the line number 7

```js
let dateToTmp;
const ValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    dateTo: yup
        .date()
        .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)
        .test('dateToTmp', 'assign value to variable', (value) => {
            dateToTmp = value;
            return true;
        })
    uebernachtungen: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
        ort: yup
            .string()
            .trim()
            .max(100, Maximum100CharactersMessage)
            .required(MandatoryFieldMessage),
        bis: yup
            .date()
            .required(MandatoryFieldMessage)
            .test('dateToCheck', 'display message', function (value) {
            // access dateTo from passed context
            return !(value > dateToTmp)
    })) 
})
```

Comment: while this might work in some cases, it devastates clean code concept. Will break in any more elaborate app (where multiple validations are done simultanously)